# Delete same values from both arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays and I want to delete the same values between the two for example

```
  $array1 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6)
  $array2 = array(5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

would have the result

```
  $array = array(1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10)
```

I tried

```
$array = array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2));
```

But clearly that just deleted duplicates leaving the matched values, as single values. Is there a quick way to do this or will this have to be done using a function?

Sorry guys, clearly I don't understand arrays. Here are the actual arrays and result of suggestions at the bottom. result should be `Coffee` and `General`.

```
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    NULL
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Milk"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "Coffee"
    [6]=>
    string(8) "Sweetner"
  }


  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    NULL
    [1]=>
    string(8) "Sweetner"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "MIlk"
    [9]=>
    string(7) "General"
  }


  array(4) {
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Milk"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "Coffee"
    [6]=>
    string(4) "MIlk"
    [7]=>
    string(7) "General"
  }
```

Comment: you can find the common values ([array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)) in two arrays and then delete those values from both the arrays

Comment: What happened to `3` in the resulting array?

Comment: Clearly you have a problem with your expectations. The result is correct, only `null` and `Sweetner` exist in both arrays and are properly filtered out. The rest are the unique values of both arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of [`array_diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php), [`array_merge()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [`array_intersect()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) is what you need here:

```
$array = array_diff(
  array_merge($array1, $array2),
  array_intersect($array1, $array2)
);
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/9OmCmgo8)

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
$intersect = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
$array     = array_diff(array_merge($array1, $array2), $intersect);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the merge of the difference of both arrays, where "difference" means "values that do not exist in the other array":

```
$array = array_merge(array_diff($array1, $array2), array_diff($array2, $array1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Only for fun and when your arrays contains string and integer values only:

`$array = array_keys(array_flip($array1) + array_flip($array2));`